# Output stream to input

Tags: bash

I was trying to do something related to git in bash.
I am a tiny bit lazy and wanted to automate the git add ., git commit and git push part.
I ran into a problem with the password part.
I did the following in bash

```
username=myusername
password=mypassword
git add .
git commit -m "Next commit"
git push
echo $username
echo $password
```

Problem is, I dont get the echo part until I input the username and password myself and it gets printed next. How do I make the echo directly to username and password part?

Comment: If the git remote you are pushing to supports SSH, you should just use an ssh key.

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-fix-git-always-asking-for-user-credentials/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a file such as Create file `git_pass.sh`:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    exec echo "$GIT_PASSWORD"
```

Then, assign your password to the GIT_PASSWORD environment variable

```
    $ GIT_PASSWORD=your_password
```

Finally, execute git command with GIT_ASKPASS environment variable. It will force password prompt and execute git_pass.sh as callback:

```
    $ GIT_ASKPASS=./git_pass.sh git push $REPO
```